# Scala equivalent of Kotlins groupingBy

Tags: scala, collections, kotlin, grouping

I can't seem to find a simple Scala equivalent of Kotlins `groupingBy` method available for Iterables, which acts like Scalas `groupBy`, but doesn't eagerly create the lists. Instead, It creates a "grouping" representation for later use.

For example, working with small arrays, groupBy will suffice:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4).groupBy(_ < 3) //Map(false -> List(3, 4), true -> List(1, 2))
```

But for large or infinite collections, it won't hold if i'm interested in operating not eagerly and only on some results.

**Edit**: Sorry, the example didn't fully express how `groupingBy` works. If the input is of length `n`, It partitions the input into potentially `1` to `n` groups. In kotlin you write:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3, 4).groupingBy(it % 3).eachCount() // { 0=1, 1=2, 2=1 }
```

And you get an intermediate `Grouping` object on which you can apply a terminating operation like `eachCount` which produces a map of results.

Comment: Do you need a Map as result? The only way to work with infinite collections in Scala is using Stream or Iterator.

Comment: Yes, I need a map. I've edited my question to show the extended capabilities of kotlins `groupingBy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in two steps.

```
val (t,f) = List(1, 2, 3, 4).partition(_ < 3)
val m = Map(true -> t, false -> f)
//Map[Boolean,List[Int]] = Map(true -> List(1, 2), false -> List(3, 4))
```

It also works for lazy collections.

```
val (t,f) = Iterator.from(1).partition(_%3<1)
val m = Map(true -> t, false -> f)
//Map[Boolean,Iterator[Int]] = Map(true -> non-empty iterator, false -> non-empty iterator)

m(true).take(12).toList
//res0: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36)

m(false).take(12).toList
//res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17)
```

Comment: Yes, I've been considering the updated information. Alas, `groupBy()` _is_ eager, and I find no convenient means to partition a lazy collection other than `partition()`, which only splits it into the two, **true** and **false**, parts. Time to put in a feature request.